# JS while loop condition

Tags: javascript

JS Guess the number game.
Everything checks out but the code get stuck in loop while (go!="yes" || go!="no" ) even input was yes or no. What did I miss?

```
// Ask user to retry
while (guess != random) {
    let go = prompt("wrong guess -_-\nWould you like to retey? (yes/no)");
    console.log(go)
    while (go!="yes" || go!="no" ) {
        go = prompt("You must enter yes or no\nWould you like to retey? (yes/no)");
        console.log(go,8)
    }
    if (go == "no") {
        break;
    }
    guess = parseInt(prompt("Enter your guess"));
}
```

Comment: When `go = "no"` it is not "yes", therefore the condition passes. When `go = "yes"` it is not "no", therefore the condition passes. When `go = "anything else"` it is not "yes", therefore the condition passes.

Answer (score 1):

OK, given your expression.

> ```
> go!="yes" || go!="no"
> ```

Let's say `go` is `wibble`

```
true || true == true
```

Now let's say `go` is `"yes"`:

```
false || true == true
```

Now let's say `go` is `"no"`:

```
true || false == true
```

There is no condition where that doesn't rock out as `true`.

---

You need to use `&&` here.

Or, you can use the `includes` method of an array which is easier to understand when eyeballing the code and even more convenient when you have a longer list of values to test:

```
if ( !["yes", "no"].includes(go) )
```

Comment: OMG I'm so dumb, yeah I should've used &&, while both not true - loop